# 80s movie about a monster in the toilet trying to pull you in

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

My dad told me about a monster movie that he watched when he was young (1980s).

He said the movie had this monster where it comes from the toilet. It's like this this hand comes out of the toilet and pulls you inside it.

The language was English and the movie was aired on TV.

Comment: This question is a bit terse and there are several movies that fit the description, for example [Ghoulies II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RmBQarrygY), [Monsturd](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364527/?ref_=sr_1) or [Bloodbath at the House of Death](http://www.britishhorrorfilms.co.uk/bloodbathatthehouseofdeath.shtml). This question would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Yuk! Well, you've already been directed to [the guidelines for ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) but it doesn't hurt to point to it again! Does your dad remember when he saw that? Did he watch it in a theater, or on TV - if so would he happen to remember which channel it would likely have aired on?

Comment: No. I think he watched it when he was small and he watched it on TV and doesn't seem like he remembers the channel and stuff.

Comment: Well, "small" is a bit vague I'm afraid :) not asking for his birthday of course, but when was he a kid? 60s? 80s?

Comment: 80s. Sorry for the vague answer though

Comment: No problem. Don't hesitate to [edit] it in, and if your dad remembers anything else, even if it seems irrelevant, edit it as well - every info's good to take :) other example - did he watch it in English? Was it a translation?

Comment: he watched it in English

Comment: I've seen something like this a couple of decades ago, they showed it to us at school. It was a short thing, not movie length. And it was more of a spoof on horror movies. At some point an old man sits down on a toilet. Then the toilet starts to make a toilet-rumble sound, then the camera pans away, some screaming I think, then the camera pans back with nobody there and the water being flushed down. Same happens to some lady, and some young person, don't remember the order. Don't remember much from it, was little at the time.

Comment: A movie comes to my mind. Maybe a Stephen King movie. A group of people in a hut. A Snake like alien (looked to me like a hand puppet with an actors arm in it) came out of a toilet in one scene. I think it  "entered" its victim and possessed him or something like that. I remember scenes in a forest with a motorcycle (2 of them try to flee with) and that the aliens move under the snow. The end involves military that tries to cover everything up (perhaps imprison or even kill the witnesses?) and I think a bigger version of the smaller snake like aliens. Can't remember the name.

Answer (score 6):

Monsters coming out of toilets was a featured element of the *[Ghoulies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoulies_(film_series))* franchise.  (The movies were obviously trying to cash in on the success of *Gremlins*, but they were fairly successful in their own right.)  A hand coming out of a toilet and grabbing a guy features prominently in *Ghoulies II* (1988).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the X-Files episode [*The Host*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(The_X-Files))?  There was a lot of attacking going on from toilets and outhouses and such.  I recall it being pretty disturbing in more than just a scatological sense ;-)

Comment: No it seems. Any other thing which mainly focuses like a "hand from a toilet"?

Comment: it was back in 80s.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was the horror movie House. I saw that scene at a friends house when I was walking through the room and it scared me of using the bathroom at night.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  That's a 3-hour-long video; your answer would be much better if you gave a time-code for the scene in question or, better yet, updated the embed URL to the correct time.